# Typescript does not see types declaration of a custom module in private repository

Tags: node.js, typescript

I made a module using typescript. I defined index.d.ts file and specified it in package.json. However, when I upload the module to a git, and try to use it in my app, I get an error about missing declaration file.

My app package Json:

*Please note, that I removed some parameters from it that does not relate to my question.*

```json
"dependencies": {
    "metaserviceframework": "git+ssh@gitlab.com:enraven/metaserviceframework.git",
}
```

index.ts of my app:

```js
import 'metaserviceframework'; // No errors
require('metaserviceframework').log.trace("test") // No errors

import {log} from "metaserviceframework"; // TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'metaserviceframework'.
```

metaserviceframework package.json:

*Please note, that I removed some parameters from it that does not relate to my question.*

```json
{
  "name": "metaserviceframework",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "build/src/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node build/src/index.js",
    "prepare": "npm run build-ts",
    "build-ts": "tsc"
  },
  "files": [
    "src/",
    "build/",
    "typing/*.d.ts",
    "typing/"
  ],
  "typing": "dist/index",
  "types": "./typing/index.d.ts",
}
```

If I import module by relative path, I can specify @types/metaserviceframework by pointing to exact folder with typings, and it does work well. However, I do not know how to do this with private repositories.

Anyway, I want it to automatically find typing files, just like it does with any other modules.